# local subrings of matrix ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ho.history-overview

When is the subring (containing 1) of a matrix ring $M_n(k)$ over a field $k$
is local?
I would be grateful for every reference concerning this matter, 
Thank you!

Comment: Do you suppose that these subrings are also $K$ algebra? If not subrings of $K$ (which may be local) may complicate things. For $n=1$, you are asking the characterization of all local subrings of a commutative field. 

Comment: Yes, I mean these subrings are also algebras over $k$. Actually I am interested in finite dimensional local rings over $k$. Any local ring $A$ can be embedded into $M_d(k)$ where $d=dim_k(A)$, but what is the minimal $n$ such that $A$ can be embedded into $M_n(k)$? Are there any estimates known?

Answer (score 2):

The ring of matrices
$
\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
   a  & b  \\\\
   0  & a \\
  \end{array}
\right).
$

This ring is isomorphic to the algebra of dual numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) which is local.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of @boris-novikov shows that the algebra of all upper triangular matrices such that the entries of the main diagonal are equal, is a local ring. The dimension of this algebra is $\frac{n^2-n}{2}+1$. I am wondering if one can find a local subalgebra of $M_n(k)$ whose dimension is greater than this number.